# How to generate 4 digits alphanumeric code in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How to generate **4 digits Alphanumeric code with out repetition** in Meteor?

Comment: Since you can add npm support. Why dont you use a library like hashids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask for 4 digits, but also say 'alphanumeric'. Either way:

```
function generate4DigitNonRepeatingNumericCode() {
  ret = "";
  while (ret.length < 4) {
    var pickANumberBetween0and9 = ("" + Math.random()).charAt(2);
    if (ret.indexOf("" + pickANumberBetween0and9) == -1)
      ret += pickANumberBetween0and9;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

That one isn't Meteor-specific, can be used in any JavaScript app. For alphanumeric we'll take a shortcut and use Meteor's `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID`:

```
function generate4CharacterNonRepeatingAlphanumericCode() {
  ret = "";
  while (ret.length < 4) {
    var pickACharacter = ("" + 
      new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID().toHexString()).charAt(0);
    if (ret.indexOf("" + pickACharacter) == -1)
      ret += pickACharacter;
  }
  return ret;
}
```